# Error con splash screen en Android 8.0 : Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable ... with resource ID #0x7f0800a5

Tags: android

tengo una aplicación con splash screen, funciona correctamente, pero en Android 8.0 me da el siguiente error, dice que no encuentra el drawable..

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.atsz7.scurls, PID: 11355
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.atsz7.scurls/com.app.atsz7.scurls.splash.SplashScreenActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.app.atsz7.scurls:drawable/splash with resource ID #0x7f0800a5
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.app.atsz7.scurls:drawable/splash with resource ID #0x7f0800a5
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800a5
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:768)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:600)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:876)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:818)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:87)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
    at com.app.atsz7.scurls.splash.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:823)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:754)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1284)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:279)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:758)
```

cargo el splash screen desde un drawable utilizando un style, este es el drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Muchas gracias!.

Comment: posiblemente estés utilizando mayúsculas o algún carácter invalido en el nombre de la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de :

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Hazlo de la siguiente manera :

```
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: Al final solo le agregue otro icono que no fuera el del launcher y funciono, puede ser por los "Adaptive Icons" que se utilizan en Android 8.0, igual tu solución se ve muy bien, muchas gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Estaba consultando una página de internet que precisamente hablaba de poner el `<item>` de otra manera y gracias a tu respuesta poniéndolo de otro modo fue que se me solucionó el problema. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Basado en el mensaje de error:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable
>   com.app.atsz7.scurls:drawable/splash with resource ID #0x7f0800a5

El problema es que estas definiendo un color como una imagen (drawable) lo cual es incorrecto:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

en tu archivo:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Elimina esa linea o asegúrate de definir en verdad una imagen `drawable` en la propiedad `android:drawable`.**

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.